# How to join 2 table same name rows into a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Maybe this question has been answered somewhere else but I didn't know how can I apply that query in my working project and I am a beginner(new) to using MySQL.

I have 2 tables in my Phpmyadmin.

table-1 looks like this :

[image: table-1 image]

and table-2 looks like this

[image: table-2 image]

By using the below query I am able to join both tables together but in different column names.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `a`.`subject`,`b`.`subject`, `a`.`date`, `a`.`start_time`, `a`.`end_time`, `b`.`date`, `b`.`start_time`, `b`.`end_time` 
from `time-table` as a 
inner join `oral_time-table` as b on a.oral_token=b.token and a.class='EIGHTH' and a.medium='English' and a.faculty='GENERAL' and a.exam='Half-Yearly'
```

The below query results in this :
[image: result]

I want both data `date` name column in ascending order in both the tables. Therefore I need to join both the tables one by one.
With only one common column name both the table rows are joined. How can I achieve this and thanks in advance...

**Desired Result :**

`date` column ascending order.

[image: desired-result]

Comment: Sorry it is not so clear what you try to achieve. Please post desired result here

Comment: Looks like pivot. Not supported. Create according stored procedure which uses dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can achieve the desired result using `UNION`.
`SELECT subject, date, start_time, end_time from table-1 UNION SELECT subject, date, start_time, end_time FROM table-2`

Comment: Thank you but I am glad if you write query also of about how I can join my data from `UNION`. It will we very very much helpful for me

Comment: Don't use `date` as any column name as it is a reserved keyword and is not a good practice.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you did not post images from phpMyadmin, see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result using `UNION`.

```
SELECT subject, `date`, start_time,
                      end_time
FROM TABLE-1
UNION
SELECT subject, `date`, start_time,
                      end_time
FROM TABLE-2
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

> Don't use date as any column name as it is a reserved keyword and is
> not a good practice.

Comment: added backticks for the column "date", because of date is a reserverd word, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D

Comment: But I am unable to add collation in date column

Comment: I created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f129a46b3338f659cfb6175af46248a3) of above SQL statement. Can you give more info what you do mean when you say "I am unable to add collation in date column" ?